# Xamarin Forms ListView Images from byte[] array

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a hard time binding a ListView Image to a byte[] array. The list is picking up the 2 records it should, but the images do not show up. I'm using MVVM pattern.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToImage" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ScrollView>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" ItemTapped="ItemTapped" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" RefreshCommand="{Binding   RefreshPicturesCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageBytes, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}"></Image> 
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Model:

```
public class Picture
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource retSource = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])value;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
            retSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }
        return retSource;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

ViewModel fields:

```
ObservableRangeCollection<Picture> _Pictures;
public ObservableRangeCollection<Picture> Pictures
    {
        get { return _Pictures ?? (_Pictures = new ObservableRangeCollection<Picture>()); }
        set
        {
            _Pictures = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Pictures");
        }
    }
```

Relevant part of ViewModel GetPictures method:

```
var bytes = await PCLHelper.LoadImage(file.Name, contentFolder);

                    Picture pic = new Picture
                    {
                        Name = file.Name,
                        ImageBytes = bytes
                    };

                    Pictures.Add(pic);
```

The binding is working because if I add a label it will display the name of the file. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Put a break point inside the converter.

Comment: Oh yeah, the converter is working. I am getting an ImageSource out of it. The ListView just isn't showing it.

Comment: Try putting your Image inside a `StackLayout` in the XAML

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but that didn't work either

Comment: OK, this is annoying, but it's my own fault I guess. I was debugging on a device and no images were showing, but when I use the emulator I am now seeing the images. Am I missing a permission or setting in developer mode on the device?

Comment: For Android you will need to add the Internet permissions.